# Is there a .NET queue class that allows for dequeuing multiple items at once?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I believe a pretty common scenario is to have a queue of items that should be processed N at a time.

For instance.. if we have `23 items` and should process `10` at a time, it would be like:

```
Process batch of 10
Process batch of 10
Process batch of 3
```

I can solve this problem in a variaty of ways. My question is: Does the .NET framework provide any class designed specifically to address this scenario? The `Queue` class would be perfect but it doesn't allow for dequeuing multiple items at once.

Comment: Can't you just dequeue 10 items in a loop and then process them? Am I missing something from your question that precludes this approach?

Comment: why don't you just enqueue complete batches of 10?

Comment: You could build an extension method that dequeues in chunks and returns an `IEnumerable` of dequeued objects

Comment: Can these be enqueued out of order or mixed?  Some queueing systems have the idea of conversations (Service Broker) where messages can be logically grouped together as a conversation so they can be processed by a single reader while other messages can be processed by their respective readers.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could create an extension method on `Queue<T>`:

```
public static class QueueExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DequeueChunk<T>(this Queue<T> queue, int chunkSize) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < chunkSize && queue.Count > 0; i++)
        {
            yield return queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var q = new Queue<char>();
q.DequeueChunk(10) // first 10 items
q.DequeueChunk(10) // next 10 items
```

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/OTcIZX

Comment: Be carefull. I do not believe `return yield` is thread safe. I would suggest to be a bit more explicit in handling the dequeue.


`public static IEnumerable<T> DequeueChunk<T>(this Queue<T> queue, int chunkSize)
    {
        var result = new List<T>();
        for (var i = 0; i < chunkSize && queue.Count > 0; i++)
        {
            result.Add(queue.Dequeue());
        }
        return result;
    }`

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this in .NET with Linq by using the `Enumerable.Range()` method along with `Select()` extension method:

`var chunk = Enumerable.Range(0, chuckCount).Select(i => queue.Dequeue()).ToList();`

This works by generating an enumerable of integers then for each integer in the new enumerable it dequeues an item out of your queue. Ensure the operation is done immediately by invoking `ToList()`.

Comment: This will crash  if the queue is smaller that chunkCount, so you'll need to guard against that.

Answer (score 1):

TPL Dataflow library offers [BatchBlock < T >](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowlinkoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)  that groups input sequence of messages into chunks of desired size.

```
 var bb = new BatchBlock<int>(10);
 var ab = new ActionBlock<int[]>((Action<int[]>)chunk=>HandleChunk(chunk));  

 bb.LinkTo(ab, new DataflowLinkOptions(){PropogateCompletion = true});

 for(int i = 0; i < 23; ++i)
 {
     bb.Post(i);
 }

 bb.Complete();
 ab.Completion.Wait();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Just so I'm clear: Whe  you `Post` to a `BatchBlock` you are assigning data to be processed. But only 10 will be processed at a time. So probably, `Post` will block que thread until some of the items returns. Right? Or is it parallel? It's probably parallel because it's from the TPL library

Comment: @andrerpena That is correct. By default ActionBlock processes messages sequentially. You can change this behavior by specifying MaxDegreeOfParalIelism in options.

Comment: I see. Thanks. So, I assume that the action `chunk=>HandleChunck(chunk)` will be executed for every 10 items (chunk will be 10 items). However, how does it know it should process the last 3 even though we didn't reach 30? Is it because of the Complete method? Will the process start only when the Complete is called?

Comment: @andrerpena: A small clarification: BatchBlock.Post() is not blocking.  It maintains an internal buffer of pending messages until they are grouped into chunk and consumed by a target block (ActionBlock)

Comment: So the Complete() method will make the "consuming" to start?

Comment: Complete() method flushes the remaining pending input messages into a chunk.   You can also call bb.TriggerBatch() at any point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94359/discussion-between-andrerpena-and-alexm).

Answer (score -1):

I might just use a simplified version to just dequeue what is in the queue, and do that at specific interval using a timer or whatever is available in the system you are using.

So after 10 seconds, if there are 10, dequeue and process, or if there are 100, do the same. It all depends on the load, work being completed etc. and expectations of latency, and response for what you are trying to achieve etc...

I would assume using the queue you are doing so not to have immediate results, but something that can execute over a longer period, like aggregation of data.

This then doesn't have a strict SLA window. it might take some benchmarking and testing to understand what the load is and what would be the preferred time interval.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> DequeueAvailable<T>(this Queue<T> queue)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < queue.Count; i++)
        {
            yield return queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This method won't work as written. `queue.Count` decrements on each iteration, so you will only dequeue ~half of the items (i.e. when `i` exceeds `queue.Count`). The loop should instead be `while (queue.Count > 0)`